Low R-squared on fama french analysis in own strategy returns
I am running a backtest of a trading strategy. In order to analyze which risks have explained the strategy returns in the past, I made a fama french analysis. I resampled the historical returns monthly and downloaded the monthly returns from Ken French's Data Library and performed a multivariate regression in python. Unfortunately, this only produces an r-squared of 18%. I have a few suspicions. Could someone help me figure out which one is correct or how I could test it.

The backtest or the regression is wrong. Either because of incorrect market data or errors in the python code.
The fama french model only works on averaged market returns. My strategy only invests in about 5 stocks at a time. In the original paper, however, regressions were performed on large market indices such as the s&p 500.
Only a very small variance can be explained by the fama french risk factors (HML, SMB, ...). This could indicate that my strategy has returns but not more (commonly recognized) risks.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. We have already reviewed the code thoroughly. If you use the returns of the S&P 500 instead of my own strategy, you get an r-squared of over 90% with the same regression model and market data provider (just like French et. Al. in the paper)

Let your observed strategy returns over $T$ months be the vector $\mathbf{r}\in \mathbb{R}^T$, and let $\mathbf{X}\in \mathbb{R}^{T\times (k+1)}$ be the design matrix whose columns are the risk-free-offset intercept (a column of ones) and the monthly realizations of the $k$ factors (e.g., $k=3$ or $5$ for the usual Fama–French sets). We estimate a linear model:
$$\mathbf{r} = \mathbf{X}\boldsymbol{\beta} + \boldsymbol{\varepsilon}$$
where $\boldsymbol{\beta}\in \mathbb{R}^{k+1}$ and $\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}$ is a noise vector. By ordinary least squares (OLS):
$$\widehat{\boldsymbol{\beta}} = \bigl(\mathbf{X}^\top \mathbf{X}\bigr)^{-1} \mathbf{X}^\top \mathbf{r}$$
and the corresponding coefficient of determination is:
$$R^2 = 1 - \frac{\sum_{t=1}^T \bigl(r_t - \widehat{r}_t\bigr)^2}{\sum_{t=1}^T (r_t - \bar{r})^2}$$
with $\widehat{r}_t$ the fitted values and $\bar{r}$ the mean of $\mathbf{r}$. When you say that substituting S&P 500 returns in place of your strategy yields an $R^2$ above 90%, that strongly suggests:

The code and Fama–French data alignment are likely correct
There is nothing inherently wrong with the standard Fama–French model or its implementation

Instead, your strategy's returns might be driven mostly by idiosyncratic effects from investing in only five stocks, so the "common" factors in Fama–French cannot explain much of the variance. We can test or falsify suspicion (1) by creating synthetic data with known factor exposures (e.g., add scaled versions of MKT, SMB, and HML plus Gaussian noise) and confirming that we recover large $R^2$ and correct $\widehat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}$. This will reveal potential errors in your Python code or data alignment if the synthetic regressions fail.
To address suspicion (2), compare the variance of your strategy's returns to that of a broad index, noting that highly concentrated portfolios can have large firm-specific residuals $\varepsilon_t$. We can even expand the regression with additional style factors or use mixed-frequency data to see if more specialized factors (e.g., industry or momentum factors) capture additional variance.
If your strategy still yields a low $R^2$ with such expansions, it supports suspicion (3): namely, that your particular long/short or concentrated picks generate returns orthogonal (or nearly so) to the standard Fama–French components. In practice, a low $R^2$ in factor regressions does not necessarily imply an error; it can reflect authentic alpha or unexplained volatility, so we should confirm that the unexplained portion truly arises from skill or structural effects (e.g., small-sample anomalies) rather than from hidden biases or data issues.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
